# I am having a Trouble to check if that param is empty or not on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am Trying to check if User_avatar is present or not from form(submitted by user).If he is select different image to update i need to go for cropping otherwise it will redirect to edit page.

But If i run bellow code on controller it is directly redirecting to edit page if i select and send image also.

### Controller

```
if @user.update(user_params)

     if((@user.user_avatar.present?) && (!params[:user_avatar].blank?) )
       format.html { render :action => 'crop'}

     else

       format.html { redirect_to edit_user_path, notice: 'user was successfully updated.' }

      format.json { head :no_content }

    end

else

   format.html { render action: 'edit' }

   format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

end

```
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:user, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h,  :user_avatar, :fname, :lname,  :city_id, :location_id, :email, :password, :course, :phone_no)
end
```

Comment: use the browser console, chrome (network tab) or firefox (net tab), you can see your post request

Comment: I am getting empty value on console. but What ever the condition i wrote is not working on controller. check if that condition what i wrote is correct.if((@user.user_avatar.present?) && (!params[:user_avatar].blank?) ) is this correct.

Comment: is it params[:user_avatar] or params[:user][:user_avatar] ? I guess, you can try with user_params[:user_avatar].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails you can use `has_key?` method which returns `true` or `false`, rewriting the above if condition

```
if @user.user_avatar.present? and params[:user].has_key?(:user_avatar)
  # your code
end
```

Comment: `and` is not the same as `&&`. `and` is control flow operator. Take a look at first case http://blog.elpassion.com/ruby-gotchas/